# Angular 2 error when injecting Http

Tags: angular, angular2-http

I am trying to port a small Angular 1 app to Angular 2 and so far I've had issues with Http that I couldn't resolve. As soon as I inject HTTP_PROVIDERS, I get the following error:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <    Evaluating
http://localhost:3000/angular2/http     Error loading
http://localhost:3000/app/main.js
```

Here's the code for my main.ts:

```
import {bootstrap} from 'angular2/platform/browser';
import {AppConverter} from './app.converter';
import {CurrencyService} from './services/service.currencies';
import {RippleService} from './services/service.ripple';
import {HTTP_PROVIDERS, Http} from 'angular2/http';

bootstrap(AppConverter, [CurrencyService, HTTP_PROVIDERS, RippleService]);
```

And here's the service where I tried to use it, although it's commented for now:

```
import {Http} from 'angular2/http';
import {Inject, Injectable} from 'angular2/core';
@Injectable()
export class RippleService {
    requestUrl: string= null;
    constructor(url: string) // public httpService:Http, url: string){ 
        this.requestUrl = url;
    }
}
```

If I remove `HTTP_PROVIDERS` from `main.ts`, the error disappears and my app displays fine.But ofcourse there is no `http service`. Either it's a bug in Angular, or I'm not doing this right (I assume it's #2).

I am using Angular 2.0.0 beta 6

Comment: did you add `<script src="/~/http.dev.js"></script>` to your html file?

Comment: share your index.html file

Comment: @Sasxa I added that and it works, thanks! In all the tutorials I've read, there was never mention of that (not even in the official Angular 2 docs)...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Http is a separate module (not included in default bundle), so you need to include it in your main html file:

```
<script src="https://code.angularjs.org/2.0.0-beta.6/http.dev.js"></script>
```

You can find more information at [official docs](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/server-communication.html), and here's the [example plunker](https://angular.io/resources/live-examples/server-communication/ts/plnkr.html).

Answer (score -2):

As Sasxa pointed out, turns out I only needed to add the following to my index.html file:

```
<script src="node_modules/angular2/bundles/http.dev.js"></script>
```

Comment: @sasxa already posted the same answer then why you fell need to post the same answer ? your accepted sign shows answer is helpful no need to post the same answer again.

Comment: I posted my answer before @sasxa, but I accepted his after he posted it. Stuff happens. Why the downvote?

Comment: but as according to displayed time interval you answered after @sexsa's answer. nd one thing more i did't downvote your answer i had just post comment. its community members who downvote your answer.